# Typescript with conditional type on Map function

Tags: typescript

Hello i'm abit stuck with typescript.
I have an array of 2 possible types because I would like to render conditional component based on the type.  I am not sure how to check for that. Here is what I have so far:

```
 {sectionedListItems.map(
            (item: TypeDataEntityTypePost | TypeSection) => {
              if (item is TypeSection) {
                return <Typography>{item.title}</Typography>;
              }
              const postItem = item as TypeDataEntityTypePost;
              return <PostItem post={postItem} key={postItem.id} />;
            }
          )}
```

Comment: What are your `TypeDataEntityTypePost` and `TypeSection`? There is nothing about TS at play here. How do you differentiate them in JS? Write that logic.

Comment: please share reproducible exampel

Comment: @brc-dd what are you talking about?

Comment: @brc-dd those types are defined in my project.

Comment: @brc-dd, there is no good way to type checking in *TypeScript*, so it's pointless to write, how these things are defined in code. OP should change his types to classes, if they are not classes.

Comment: @brc-dd woa thats a potential way... however i get a typescript error saying the property title does not exist on types TypeSection | TypeDataEntityTypePost

Comment: @brc-dd optional chaining did not work either... still seems to complain because title doesn't exist on one of the types described

Comment: @brc-dd do you think maybe the problem is my design? perhaps this error is avoided with a better design?

Comment: @brc-dd  So i have an some data: in the form of  Array<TypeDataEntityTypePost | TypeSection> ,  I want to map this data and return the Correct Component depending on the Type.  is that a bad design?

Comment: @brc-dd that worked! thanks alot. that was my first time using "in" operator

Answer (score 0):

If there is a `title` property in `TypeSection` but not in `TypeDataEntityTypePost`, then you can simply do this:

```
  {sectionedListItems.map((item: TypeDataEntityTypePost | TypeSection) => {
    if ('title' in item) return <Typography>{item.title}</Typography>
    return <PostItem post={item} key={item.id} />
  })}
```

There is no need of the `as`-cast too. TypeScript will treat `item` in any statement outside that block as `TypeDataEntityTypePost`. Type guarding using the `in` operator is supported in TS 2.7 and above. [Reference.](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10485)

[Documentation.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in)

Answer (score -1):

Let change:

```js
if (item is TypeSection)
```

to

```js
if (item instanceof TypeSection)
```

Comment: I think instanceOf only applies to classes not types/interfaces...

Comment: Yeah, but if you need type checking, I would go this way. I mean changing your types or interfaces to classes. Other ways of type checking are... messy, to be honest.